# Why not Always Random Forest in Place of Linear or Logistic Regression

Tags: random-forest

Why Don't we use Random Forest always in place of Linear or Logistic Regressions. When will Linear and Logistic out perform Random Forest.

Comment: "Out perform" in what sense?  Speed? Interpretability? Simplicity? Generalizability?

Answer (score 5):

**Advantages of linear models**

1) They are much easier to interprete

2) You can do more than just predictions, e.g. test statistical hypotheses

3) They don't require much space to store

4) They are very fast to fit, depending on the chosen algorithm

When can linear models outperform a random forest?

- If you have enough time and knowledge to do smart feature construction/interaction selection etc. and the data set is not too large.
- ...?

Comment: Small addition: Parametric models (1) allow for 'true' regression in that the predicted response is truly continuous (2) the model has less variance (hence performs better in cases were data is not large and the model assumptions are met).

Comment: Linear models also work well for large data consisting of high cardinality factors ( as in web advertising. Factors might be web site, web domain, advert, ad campaign, ..

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the points raised by @Michael M, we have to look at what exactly we mean by "outperform".

One purpose of many statistical analyses is prediction. For this, I think RF might always be better than linear regression (I'm not sure about that, but it seems to be so, more knowledgeable users can bring up exceptions and details, Michael mentions one possibility; and, in a comment, @whuber mentions another).

But sometimes prediction is only part of our aim and sometimes it isn't even a part. Another goal of many analyses is explanation. Linear and logistic regression results explain the relationships among the independent and dependent variables in ways that may add to knowledge - or that may indicate some problem in the data or something to look into or whatnot.

In his wonderful book *Statistics as Principled Argument* Robert Abelson talks about another reason why regression might be better: It can be part of a principled argument in ways that would be difficult for random forests.

Comment: (+1) In many physical applications an appropriate linear regression model is virtually certain to outperform any Random Forest for prediction.

Answer (score 0):

Random Forest is good for sort of "catching" joint effects of 2 or more variables, meaning if feature 1 is above some threshold and feature for example below some other threshold, they will have different effect on target variable then you could model with linear relationship due to linear regression being additive model (you just sum up portion of effects of each feature). This means that random forest can outperform linear models in prediction, but since RF is ensamble method (comprised of many trees voting for the final prediction) it means you cannot interpret how each feature variable is affecting target variable.

Comment: On the contrary, random forests can be used to infer variable importances.

Comment: @gunes can you elaborate more, i'm interested.

Comment: In a nutshell, features are assessed based on how they contribute to splitting criteria (e.g. gini, entropy). scikit-learn RF implementation also has a method for calculating importances. You may resort to the wiki link: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Random_forest#/Variable_importance for deep dive.

Comment: @gunes One should note though that variable importance measured by Gini has been shown to be very biased towards variables with high carnality and correlated predictors (see work by Strobl et al, Altmann et al.)

Comment: Oh, you're right. I wasn't saying that it is the correct way to do it, just opposing the statement "*you cannot interpret how each feature variable is affecting target variable*" to say that there are indeed ways to interpret feature effects.

Comment: @gunes Oh I see, this I completely agree on!

Comment: @gunes im sure there's many ways of doing the same thing in statistics, that's the beauty of it, but there are some guidelines in practical methods and what are they best used for. Just saying that by going for more complex models, you loose interpretability (2.1.3. The Trade-Off Between Prediction Accuracy and Model
Interpretability - Introduction to Statistical Learning)

Comment: @NemanjaBoskovic You can use partial dependency plots or other methods such as SHAP to infer variable impact. You can also use permutation feature importance to get the feature importance (which you can also do with Logistic Regression)

Answer (score -1):

Random forest , Original learning dataset is randomly divided into several subsets of equal size, so its takes lot of memory and learning may be slow compared to linear and logistic regression.

and Random forest do both classification and regression.

Comment: The subsets don't need to be equal size.

Comment: @bi_scholar okay.. 

by the way i red online in one  article that subset needs equal size that's why i wrote.

Comment: I just realized that I might have misunderstood your answer. Were you referring to the bootstrap sampling at the beginning of each tree? In this case you're definitely correct. I thought you are referring to the splits in a tree.